# Java same function name with different type of HashMap input variable?

Tags: java, function, class, hashmap, overloading

These two functions in the same class with identical names does not cause an error, because the input variable types are different. (`String` and `int`)

```
public static int sameName(HashMap<Integer, String> _map, String _var) {
    return 42;
}

public static int sameName(HashMap<Integer, String> _map, int _var) {
    return 42;
}
```

In this case, the variable types are also different, still this causes an error. The first one uses a `HashMap<Integer, String>`, the second uses `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`.

```
public static int sameName(HashMap<Integer, String> _map, int _var) {
    return 42;
}

public static int sameName(HashMap<Integer, Integer> _map, int _var) {
    return 42;
}
```

Why is this?
Apart from choosing a different function name and flipping the order of variables, are there any more professional ways to solve this, without manipulating the consistency of the names of my functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics are erased after compilation, so the signatures of both methods is just:

```
int sameName(HashMap, int)
```

Change "sameName" to something more meaningful if the methods really are doing two different things.

Comment: Thank you. They are doing the same thing with different data-types. (Key lookup by value.)